# How can I free space on my netbook?

Tags: disk-usage

I have a netbook with 16GB memory and 1GB RAM (Mini Dell 9). Computer properties shows 14.4GB total capacity, 10GB used and 3.6GB free. Is it possible to free more memory?

I have also a HD card with 32GB but it's only there to store data, it is formated as an MS-DOS for portability and shows 17.5GB free.

Comment: Music and video can take up lots of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details about your system, I really can't help you with what to remove.

Plus, they're your files and thus you'd have to make the final decision about what to do with the space anyways (deleting files, etc.)

What I *can* do, however, is show you a quick way to get a graphical breakdown of all of your files and the space they're taking.

---

Open the Unity dash by clicking the Ubuntu logo with the swirly things:

[image]

or by pressing the <kbd>Windows/Super</kbd> key.

Once the dash is open, just type in `Disk Usage` and select Disk Usage Analyzer:

[image]

Note, your icon will look a little different - I've got the Numix Circle icon theme. Just click on the application titled `Disk Usage Analyzer`.

Once it's open, you should see a window that looks similar to this one:

[image]

It lists all files & folders on the left from largest to smallest, as well as a graphical visualization of it on the right.

Have a poke around in this tool, it's very useful for finding stuff that's taking up space.

Beyond manually clearing up space, you can try running the following commands to try and clear up some space that's being used by unneeded packages:

`sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean`

Then, try installing [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/). It's has a "Janitor" feature that will clean up old an unused files for you:

[image]

Comment: The disk usage analyser is good but only shows the files and the space they are taking. It doesn't say which ones I can delete.

Comment: Ubuntu tweak is great. I have deleted all the caches and the Old Kernel and freed about 3GB out of 14.4 total. But the janitor doesn't seem to be able to delete 77 Package Configs and 43 Unneeded Packages. Any idea why?

Comment: @ThierryMsika Well, the disk usage analyzer is good for finding out what's taking up space, so *you* can decide if you want to delete if you want. As for not being able to delete the configs and packages, did you run those commands I listed? `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean`?

Comment: Why do I get "Could not scan folder "/" or some of the folders it contains.  Permission denied" message in the Disk Analyzer?

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove removed the Unneeded Packages then Janitor was able to remove the Package Configs. Thanks

Comment: @ThierryMsika Ah, good. As for why you get that error from Disk Analyzer, try launching it with `sudo baobab` and it should work. If my answer helped resolve your issue, would you mind upvoting and marking my answer as such? (clicking the up arrow and green checkmark) That's the accepted way of saying thank you to the person who put in the time and effort to make an answer on this site, and it also helps people who may view this question in the future to easily see what the solution was!

Comment: Yes "sudo baobab" works. I did the thing with up arrow and check mark but they are not obvious nor intuitiv.

Comment: @ThierryMsika Awesome! Well, now you know what to do when an answer solves your problem! ;)

Comment: Terminal shows this:               "(baobab:20986): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 14654 was not found when attempting to remove it

(baobab:20986): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 16968 was not found when attempting to remove it"             Is it a problem I should correct?

Comment: @ThierryMsika No :) Those errors are fairly normal with any GUI program - they're normally just hidden because you normally launch the program without a terminal. If the program doesn't crash or act incorrectly, the errors are most likely inconsequential.